# How do I perform array operations on J classes?

Tags: j

I'm playing around with J's object-orientation facilities. Consider the following extremely contrived code:

```
coclass 'Object'
create =: 3 : 'state =: 0'
increment =: 3 : 'state =: state + y'
destroy =: codestroy

cocurrent 'base'
objects =: (0 conew 'Object') , (0 conew 'Object') , 0 conew 'Object'
```

Let's say I want to call the `increment` method on each of the objects in the `objects` array. How do I do this in a J-tastic kind of way? The only way I could come up with was an intermediate verb:

```
o_increment =: 4 : 0
    for_o. y do.
        increment__o x
    end.
)

3 o_increment objects
```

This works but is not very convenient. Is there a better way?

Comment: I get a value error trying to run that code but shouldn't `increment objects` do it?

Comment: The short answer is `3 verb def 'increment__y x'"0 objects` but the longer answer is OOP in J is much coarser than in other languages, and this kind of thing is done infrequently. More typical is to have the object's members themselves be arrays, and operate on those arrays in toto.

Comment: @DanBron Agreed. I've been doing J for a while now and OOP in J isn't something I plan to do a lot of. My question was academic, not necessarily practical. "If you were to do this, how would you do it…"

Comment: @DanBron Why don't you turn your comment into an answer so we can tidy this question up? If you don't do so within a week or so, I'll do it myself.

Comment: @GregoryHigley Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Because object references are a part of J's morphology, rather than syntax**, they're harder to manipulate at run-time than other data.  That is, object references are baked into names, rather than specified as free parameters.

So, there's two ways invoke a method on an array of objects, and both require explicit code. The first way — rarely used except in unusual circumstances — is to generate and then execute strings representing the fully-qualified name, including a direct (explicit) locative.

```
3 apply&>~ 'increment_' ,L:0 objects ,&.> '_'
```

**Much more common** is to use an indirect reference in an explicit code block, using one of the pre-defined local variables as the locative. For example:

```
3 dyad def 'increment__y x'"0 objects
```

or, equivalently:

```
incrementObjs =: dyad define
    increment__x y
)

objects incrementsObjs"0]  3
```

In fact, JSoftware made a major [backwards-compatibility-breaking change to the language](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/release/argnames.htm) in version 6 specifically to make this pattern more convenient.  Previously (i.e. prior to v6), you would have had to write something like:

```
incrementObjs =: dyad define
    o =. x.          NB.  x and y used to be spelled x. and y.
    increment__o y   NB.  but increment__x. would raise an error 
)
```

In any case, note that this `incrementsObjs"0 objects` reformulation of your explicit `for_o. objects do.` loop is actually not specific to OOP at all; it's the standard automation of iteration provided by J's array-oriented nature.

**Which leads me to the real answer** to your question: *J is fundamentally an array-oriented language, and its objects are usually coarser-grained than they are in more familiar languages like Java or C#.*

In those languages, it's common to have a collection of objects; in J, it's more common to have an object of collections. That is, the objects in mainstream OOP languages are "small", in some sense. In J, objects are large, because *all* data in J is large (I don't mean this in the physical "big data", GB sense: I mean it in a conceptual, philosophical, ℕ sense).

Therefore the actual most common way to express your problem:

```
coclass 'Object'
create =: 3 : 'state =: 0'
increment =: 3 : 'state =: state + y'
destroy =: codestroy

cocurrent 'base'

objects =: 'Object' conew 0 0 0
```

Note that last line there `objects =: 'Object' conew 0 0 0`; the original was 
`objects =: (0 conew 'Object') , (0 conew 'Object') , 0 conew 'Object'`.

**That is: rather than an array of 3 objects, we created *one* object, with *an array of 3 values*.**

Note also that *that's the only line of code I changed*. The "refactoring" to go from an object handling scalar values to one managing an array of any number of values took zero bytes of code-changes.

But what about incrementing all the objects? Before, you had to say:

```
3 dyad def 'increment__y x'"0 objects
```

Now, you only need say:

```
increment__objects 3
```

And that's why this is the standard approach to OOP in J <sup>1</sup>.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Well, a cynic might say that J's fundamental array nature in some way obviates or even conflicts with the aims of OOP, and that the OO features available in J were bolted-on as an afterthought during the ascendence of OOP in the late 90s *cough*Perl*cough*, but I'm no cynic. At least not publicly.</sub>

<sub>OOP has its place in J, especially for organizing large components in a dynamic system; it's used applied differently than in language whose fundamental philosophy is OO, rather than AO.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

```
 inl_z_ =: (cocurrent@] ".@] [)"1 0
```

allows you to run code in 1 or a list of objects

'state =: >: state' inl objects

To disagree with Dan, J is actually fantastic at dealing with lists of objects with this function.  You can obviously prefilter the list in objects prior to calling the code.  Search for inlC (and inlA) in mailing list for more advanced uses of inl such as interacting with caller locale parameters.

To agree with Dan, making an object has to have a good reason compared to the alternative of having a list of the would-be properties (and then a table of all of the record instances).  One good reason tends to be that there are resources to allocate and free